# Update same row with multiple Update statement at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, ajax, sql-update

I am trying to update a single MS SQL server table row with multiple ajax call; each call tries to update different records of the same row.
I get the updated values some times and some times all the records I am trying to update becomes null. I have checked the ajax calls and the values are being sent ok.

Can anybody give me any idea what wrong I am doing or what should I check to get the issue ?

To give you better idea about the scenario :
I have two panels with some inputs. There is a review button - when clicked two ajax calls for each of the panel are made sending the input values for corresponding panels. Both ajax call are suppose to update the same row in a table - but different records.
In the same review button click a page is loaded in a iframe to show the values just updated.

Comment: Not without more context and code, no.

Comment: @Dan : I am not doing anything complex - Updating a single row on ajax calls - as described in the scenario when I click the review button some times I get the data updated and some times all the records I am trying to update becomes null. Anything you would have checked to get what's happening ? Or anything you can think of might happening ?